# Rails params going missing between browser and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page in my Rails app to create an Outlet. It has a `select` tag:

```
<select name="outlet[alliance_id]" id="outlet_alliance_id">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="95cca47e664e44ca90be7ce6cf122f74">Alliance #1</option>
</select>
```

But if I select the 'Alliance #1' option and `POST` the form, the parameter doesn't come through to the controller:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "outlet"=>{
    ...
    "alliance_id"=>"",
    ...
  }
}
```

I have some identical ERB code for a `select` tag on the #edit page for the same object, and it works fine. Where could this parameter be going missing?

Comment: Can you check if it's being sent through browser's network tab? (Search for your request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... my bad. I had a piece of old code further down the page that dynamically added hidden fields for all attributes on an Outlet, except for ones that I specified - and I forgot about it, and hadn't specified `alliance_id`.

I found it after changing `alliance_id` to `doy_yang_chee_rupatatup_tup_boing` (long story, bit of an in-joke) and seeing that `alliance_id` was *still* coming through as a parameter.